# How to Return Two Partials in one AJAX Call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my Controller I am returning a partial via AJAX, is there a way I can load two partials via an AJAX call?

```
// AJAX?
        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        return PartialView("_ViewSongAmendmentsWriters", model);
```

Comment: Do you want to concatenate two partials or load two separate partials?

Comment: Two separate partials would be fine. As they are two tables of results.

Comment: ..and how might you consume this "dual" partial view that comes from a single request? You'd need some sort of envelope around the parts. AFAIK, this doesn't exist. Perhaps returning JSON and constructing your tables client-side might be more appropriate?

Comment: Would `return RedirectToAction` be an option? As I dont want to use `JsonResult` really.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to return a `JsonResult` containing the html for both partials. We're using an extension to convert a partial to html for returning in AJAX calls.

This extension is an extension on the `Controller`:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static string PartialViewToHtml(this Controller controller, string viewName)
    {
        return controller.PartialViewToHtml(viewName, null);
    }

    public static string PartialViewToHtml(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        if (model != null)
            controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var context = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, result.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, writer);
            result.View.Render(context, writer);
            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

You could then write your `Action` as follows:

```
// AJAX?
if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return View(model);
}
return Json(new 
{ 
    html1: this.PartialViewToHtml("_ViewSongAmendmentsWriters", model), 
    html2: this.PartialViewToHtml("_PartialView2", model2) 
});
```